# Unity3D UI Text string from json not correctly showing

Tags: c#, json, string, newline

I'm getting string from JSON and applying this string to UI Text.text.

```
textAZ = jsonObject.GetString("haqqinda_az").ToString();
aboutText.text = textAZ;
```

But it is showing \n and \r symbols in Game Window. I want this symbols breaking new lines. Picture here:

[image from play mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRLw7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newlines symbols are already escaped, but you can undo that:

```
textAZ = jsonObject.GetString("haqqinda_az").ToString();
textAZ = textAZ.Replace("\\n","\n").Replace("\\r","\r");
aboutText.text = textAZ;
```